# phoenix framework how to mock socket in js

Tags: javascript, phoenix-framework

I have not found any info on the web about how to mock phoenix `socket` and before digging into source code, which is quite [lengthy](https://github.com/mspanc/phoenix_socket/blob/master/vendor/socket.js), wanted to find out if someone has some solution already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a simple mock object

```
const socketMock = {
  channel() {
    const channel = {
      join() { return channel },
      receive(msg, callback) {
        setTimeout(() => msg === 'ok' && callback(responseMock), 0)
        return channel
      },
      on() {},
      leave() {}
    }
    return channel
  }
}
```

Comment: Please select your own answer as correct - if that was a solution for you.

Comment: @Ash I can only select it in 2 days

Comment: My bad. Forgot about that rule.

Comment: `responseMock` is not defined in the example

Comment: @MichaelOliver it is an object that looks like a response